# Is there a field $F$ which is isomorphic to $F(X,Y)$ but not to $F(X)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Is there a field $F$ such that $F \cong F(X,Y)$ as fields, but $F \not \cong F(X)$ as fields?

I know only an example of a field $F$ such that $F$ isomorphic to $F(x,y)$ : this is something like $F=k(x_0,x_1,\dots)$. But in this case we have $F \cong F(x)$.

This is related to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225896) question on MO. However, it doesn't follow obviously from $R \not \cong R[x]$ that $\text{Frac}(R) \not \cong \text{Frac}(R)(X)$ (I'm not even sure that the given $R$ is an integral domain...).

These questions could be relevant: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448250) ; [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388291).

Thank you very much!

Comment: One could ask about a generalization: let $(k_i)_{i \in I \cup J}$ be distinct cardinals, is there a field $F$ such that $F \cong F(X_s, s \in k_i)$ for $i \in I$ and $F \not \cong F(X_s, s \in k_j)$ for $j \in J$.

Comment: It would be also nice to have an example of a _field_ $F$ such that $F[x] \not \cong F \cong F[x,y]$ (and the same generalization as above can be done), or a ring $R$ such that $R \not \cong R[x,y]$ but $R[x] \cong R[x,y,z]$.

Comment: Writing $\phi:F(X,Y)\to F$ we must have $F=\phi(F)(A,B)=\phi^2(F)(A,B,C,D)=\cdots$ in which one might hope that $F=(\bigcap \phi^n(F))(A,B,C,D,\cdots)$ but I see no way to prove that.

Comment: In my above comment, I wanted to say "of an _integral domain_ $F$" ($F \cong F[x,y]$ isn't possible for a field $F$, since $x$ isn't invertible). Notice that there is no field $F$ such that $F(x,y) \not \cong F \cong F(x)$, because we would have $F \cong F(x) \cong F(y) \cong F(x)(y) = F(x,y)$.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258647/

Comment: The ring constructed in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225896/r-is-isomorphic-to-rx-y-but-not-to-rx) seems to be a domain ; does its field of fractions $F$ satisfies $F \not \cong F(X)$ (knowing $R \not \cong R[X]$) ?

Comment: The example given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818409) shows that we can have a domain $A$, with field of fractions $B$, such that $A \not \cong A[X]$ but $B \cong B(X)$.