# Can we have $A \cong \mathrm{Frac}(A)[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

> Is there an integral domain $A$, with field of fractions $K$, such that $A$ is isomorphic to $K[X]$ ?

Such a ring $A$ has to be a PID, which is not a field (i.e. PID of Krull dimension $1$), and is infinite. Basic examples as $A = \Bbb Z, k[t], ...$ don't work. 
I can notice that $A^{\times} \cong K^{\times}$, which is a strange property, but this isomorphism is not necessarily coming from the inclusion $A \subset K$.
Maybe I'm missing an easy obstruction for such a ring to exist, and anyway I don't find any counterexample.

Thank you!

Comment: In the example below, we have a domain $A$, with field of fractions $B$, such that $A \not \cong A[X]$ but $B \cong B(X)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $B = k(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots)$ and $A = B[x_0]$. Then $\mathrm{Frac}(A) \cong B$.